# Is it possible to smooth dirt/clay walls?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I know that you can smooth stone walls:

[image: smoothed stone]

But my fortress is in a clay/dirt layer, and i would like to smooth the walls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Clay and dirt can't be improved at all, except by digging them out and building stone block walls in their place. For this reason, clay/dirt layers should generally be reserved for underground farms (since they don't require irrigation), and the real fortress should be built below them, in true dwarfish stone.